# Onclick HTML Div

Tags: javascript, html

I have a text to speak script and it is called by Javascript on HTML like this;

```
<head>
<script src="speakClient.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="speak('type text to speak here')">Talk</button>
<div class="article">
<p>Sample text is here!!</p>
</div>
<div id="audio"></div>
</body>
```

Currently when 'Talk' button is pressed, the predefined text (in this case "type text to speak here") will be speak by TTS.

How to change it when button is pressed, it speaks whatever text inside div.article instead of predefined text?

Edit: Link to JS https://github.com/kripken/speak.js/blob/master/speakClient.js

Thanks in advance

Comment: can u make a js fiddle?

Comment: I don't think I can do it JSFiddle as it contains a lot of external libraries and voices files.

Comment: @SamSuresh, can you post here, what speak method look likes?

Comment: Here it is
https://github.com/kripken/speak.js/blob/master/speakClient.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the textual content of an element easily with `jQuery`:

```
var textToSpeak = $('div.article').text();
```

Then set the onclick function dynamically:

```
<button onclick="speak($('div.article').text())">Talk</button>
```

It is better than using pure JavaScript and `innerHTML` property, as potential `HTML` tags will be stripped with this solution.

Comment: `<head>
    <script src="speakClient.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
var textToSpeak = $('div.article').text();
  </script>
    <button onclick="speak($('div.article').text())">Talk</button>
    <div class="article">
    <p>Sample text is here!!</p>
    </div>
    <div id="audio"></div>
  </body>`

Comment: First, the `textToSpeak` variable was just an example, it is unused. Second, did you referenced the JQuery library? Third, what does "doesn't work" mean? Please specify! Fourth, maybe you should learn some basic JS instead of waiting for others to completely solve your issue.

Comment: Sorry I'm not a javascript coder. Creating this plugin for a CMS which has jQuery loaded. Yes, I should learn JS. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="article">
<script>var text = "Sample text is here!!";</script>
</div>

<button onclick="speak(text)">Talk</button>
```

Comment: Not exactly. I want it to speak text inside a div. The text in the div is captured from somewhere else which will change always and shouldn't predefined.

Answer (score 0):

Give an id to the `<p>` tag, and then you can pull out the value by calling `innerHtml`.

Example:

```
<button onclick="speak(document.getElementById('textToUse').innerHTML)">Talk</button>
<div class="article">
<p id="textToUse">Sample text is here!!</p>
</div>
```

Comment: It is not possible not assign id to p tag as the article is from CMS using WYSIWYG editor.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following script to the element of which you want the text read.

```
onclick="speak(this.innerText);"
```

Comment: you mean add to article class? <div class="article" onclick="speak(this.innerText)">

Comment: Yes, that should work. I created a JSFiddle with a different TTS script. You can check it out here.
http://jsfiddle.net/yac07qt1/

Comment: Just another question. I'm going to reference to an existing Class or element like 'article' without text input.